# Python Programming Unintentional Infinite Loop

Tags: python

```
counter=0
initials=0
name1=raw_input("Please enter your first name!")
name2=raw_input("Please enter your middle name!")
name3=raw_input("Please enter your last name!")
option=str(raw_input("a)Print the length of my name\nb)Print\nc)Exit\nChoose one of the options."))
while option != "c" or option != "C":
    if (option=="a" or option=="A"):
        print "Your first name has " + str(len(name1)) + " letters."
        print "Your second name has " + str(len(name2)) + " letters."
        print "Your last name has " + str(len(name3)) + " letters."
    elif (option=="b" or option=="B"):
        print name1[0] + "." + name2[0] + "." + name3[0]
    elif (option=="c" or option=="C"):
        break
```

This is my code. It keeps going into an infinite loop for some reason. How do I make it stop once the user selects their option? I just need there to be input of the option the user selects once.

Comment: The indentation of your code seems off. Please check.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the line

```
option=str(raw_input("a)Print the length of my name\nb)Print\nc)Exit\nChoose one of the options."))
```

at the end of the while loop. This will ask the user again for input, and if it is `c` or `C`, it will exit.

You should also change your `while` condition. Using `or` will cause it to be always `False`. You should probably use `while True` instead (as `c` input is checked inside the loop).

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you, just need to change your while condition to `True` and change your option statement's position.

```
counter=0
initials=0
name1=raw_input("Please enter your first name!")
name2=raw_input("Please enter your middle name!")
name3=raw_input("Please enter your last name!")

while True:
    option=str(raw_input("a)Print the length of my name\nb)Print\nc)Exit\nChoose one of the options."))
    if (option=="a" or option=="A"):
        print "Your first name has " + str(len(name1)) + " letters."
        print "Your second name has " + str(len(name2)) + " letters."
        print "Your last name has " + str(len(name3)) + " letters."
    elif (option=="b" or option=="B"):
        print name1[0] + "." + name2[0] + "." + name3[0]
    elif (option=="c" or option=="C"):
        break
```

Comment: In order to avoid typing `option=="c" or option=="C"`, or similar typing, you could just set the variable `option` as  `option = str(raw_input("x")).lower()` as showed in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rrrub/ee4257a737c3e8f8ca42b8c9bfa5a97b)

Comment: @gist – rrrub yes you are right, we can do this also...
 `option=str(raw_input("a)Print the length of my name\nb)Print\nc)Exit\nChoose one of the options.")).lower()`
after this we don't have to add `or` condition for checking capital `letter(option=="C"`)